# Google analytics background events

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

Is there a way to tell Google Analytics that certain events shouldn't be counted towards session data?

Specifics: I have an Android app that uses Google Analytics. It has a service that crunches some data in the background, and reports stats on those tasks to GA. (The background tasks happen while the app is inactive). It seems that sending data this way is creating a ton of spurious sessions in GA, since it thinks that the events mean that the user is using the app and thus is initiating a new session.

How can I say to GA, "hey I'm sending you this event, but don't count it as a session"?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [non-interaction event flag](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#non-interaction_events). I'm not sure if it will do exactly what you're looking for (it's effect on bounce rate is all that's documented), but it's the closest thing I'm aware of to what you're describing.